# TSQL Procedure returning multiple rows of data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm busy trying to rewrite some PostgreSQL stored procedures/functions for SQL Server 2014s TSQL.

I am struggling to return my values from this stored procedure though, this one is just a test but I am trying to return multiple rows of data in this case the for the two variables si_code and co_desc.

I have my procedure as follows (as a test)

```
if (object_id('p_get_serial')) is not null
   drop procedure p_get_serial
go

create procedure p_get_serial(@par01 char(20), @par02 integer)
as

   declare
      @co_num integer,
      @co_desc char(20),
       @si_code char(20),
       @log char(40)

   declare mycur cursor for
      select co_num, co_desc
       from colours
       where co_num <= @par02

   open mycur
   fetch next from mycur into @co_num,
                              @co_desc

   while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   begin

      set @si_code = ''

    select @si_code = si_code
       from sitems
       where si_co_num = @co_num

       set @log = @co_desc + ' ' + @si_code
       raiserror(@log,0,1) with nowait

      fetch next from mycur into @co_num, @co_desc

   end
   close mycur deallocate mycur

go

exec p_get_serial @par01 = 'paramater01', @par02 = 10
```

what is the best way to return my results knowing that there will be several rows?

Comment: You should show your input table and desired output, it looks like you should not be using a cursor at all (they are an approach of last resort).  What is the intention of the unconditional raiserror?

Comment: in this example I don't need the cursor this is just a test, the real procedure is too complex to do without a cursor

Comment: You might also consider a Function that outputs a table.   But if the SP is the only way - create/define a Table Variable and output that at the end of the sp.  Also - generally cursors are "bad" in sql-server (poor overall performance).  If you can find a way to avoid cursors you'll have better performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In T-SQL you do not need to declare a cursor. Just `select` what you need and it will be available to the client app.

Cursor is Oracle/DB2/PostgreSQL etc way of returning data. SQL Server does not need it.

```
create procedure p
as
    select 1 as a
```

returns a recordset containing one record with one column.

```
create procedure p
as
    select 1 as a, 'a' as b
    union select 2, 'b'
```

returns two rows each with two columns.

Example of a more complex processing before returning a result set:

```
create procedure p
as
begin
    declare @a int, @b varchar(10)

    select @a = 1
    select @b = convert(varchar(10), @a)

    select @a = @a + 1

    select @a as a, @b as b -- this will be the resultset returned to the client
end
```

Comment: I won't be able to achieve the results I need with a single select, the procedure I'm trying to recreate is a lot more involved

Comment: You can design your procedure however complex you like, I am just showing you the technology you will have to use under MS SQL: your final `select` returns the result set to the client. Any processing that builds that dataset is totally up to you. But also keep in mind that if you do not need a result set, you can also https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is, just save the data for each row in a temp table or table variable and just write a SELECT statement at the the end of the Stored Procedure.
Your question is not clear what you need exactly, you have a cursor and while loop, they seem to be redundant